# How to remove sickbeard when installed via git

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

Good morning askubuntu! I've decided to stop using sickbeard and would like to get it disabled and completely removed from my server (16.04).

Initially I installed sickbeard via GIT

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/midgetspy/Sick-Beard.git .sickbeard
```

I don't see any mention of special apt.sources in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
locate sickbeard | more
```

only turns up files in ~/.sickbeard/xxxxx

```
drew@mimi:/etc/apt$ sudo service sickbeard status
● sickbeard.service - LSB: starts instance of Sick Beard
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sickbeard; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2016-11-21 08:34:43 PST; 19min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15473 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sickbeard stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1220 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sickbeard start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 18 20:30:35 mimi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts instance of Sick Beard...
Nov 18 20:30:36 mimi sickbeard[1220]: Starting SickBeard
Nov 18 19:31:32 mimi systemd[1]: Started LSB: starts instance of Sick Beard.
Nov 21 08:34:28 mimi systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: starts instance of Sick Beard...
Nov 21 08:34:28 mimi sickbeard[15473]: Stopping SickBeard
Nov 21 08:34:43 mimi systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: starts instance of Sick Beard.
```

Thanks!

Comment: According to the output above, there's at least `/etc/init.d/sickbeard` outside of `~/.sickbeard`. Try running `sudo updatedb` and then `locate sickbeard`.

Answer (score 2):

`Git clone` does not install the software on your system. It only downloads the source code to your computer. Then you probably had to enter the directory (`~/.sickbeard`) where you downloaded the source, and then you issued `./configure` and `make` and `sudo make install` commands in the terminal, to compile and install the program.

Likewise, in terminal, if you navigate to the same source folder (`cd ~/.sickbeard`) and issue a `make uninstall` it should uninstall the program for you. Then you can issue a `cd` command, and then `sudo rm -r ~/.sickbeard` to completely delete the source code.